# get user input using Request in laravel and pass it for validation

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to laravel.Here i have a form where i have to fill up a name field and send it to controllers store() method for validation. Otherwise it will show custom error.But whenever i submit the form with or without input i am getting the following error.

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mylaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 221 and defined

for experiment purpose i am catching the user input using the following format

```
$data = $request->input('name');
```

**create.blade.php:**

```
<h1>login form</h1>
      @if($errors->has())
        <div><span> Opps !! </span></br>
          <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li> {{ $error }}</li>    
            @endforeach
          </ul>
        </div>
      @endif
   {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'user','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}

   {!!Form::label('name','Your name')!!}
   {!!Form::text('name')!!}
   </br>

   {!!Form::submit('submit')!!}
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

**store() method in userController.php file:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $data = $request->input('name');

    $rules = array(
       'name' => 'unique:users,name|required|alpha_num'

    );

    // Create a new validator instance.
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){

        $errors=$validator->messages();
        return Redirect::route('user.create')->withErrors($validator);

    }else{

            return Redirect::route('user.index');
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `array` inside `Validator::make`.

Right now your are passing string in the form of `$data` variable.

For example :

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('name' => 'Dayle'),
    array('name' => 'required|min:5')
);
```

DOCS : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

Answer (score 3):

According to your error,`Validator` expects it parameters to be array, but you are passing a string there as `$data=  $request->input('name')` . So, you should pass array in `Validator::make()` . Below code should work for you.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'unique:users,name|required|alpha_num'
]);
```

Here is the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation) if you want to explore more .

Answer (score 2):

you have pass your params as array in validation,so your code will be

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
//
    $data = $request->all();

$rules = array(
   'name' => 'unique:users,name|required|alpha_num'

);

// Create a new validator instance.
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
if($validator->fails()){

    $errors=$validator->messages();
    return Redirect::route('user.create')->withErrors($validator);

}else{

        return Redirect::route('user.index');
    }

}

}
```